# How can one extract rdf:about or rdf:ID properties from triples using SPARQL?

Tags: java, rdf, semantic-web, triplestore, rdfs

It seemed a trivial matter at the beginning but so far I have not managed to get the unique identifier for a given resource using SPARQL. What I mean is given, e.g., `rdf:Description rdf:about="http://..."` and then some properties identifying this resource, what I want to do is to first find this very resource and then retrieve all the triples given some URI.

I have tried naïve approaches by writing statements in a `WHERE` clause such as:

```
?x rdf:about ?y and ?x rdfs:about ?y
```

I hope I am being precise.

Comment: It's SPARQL, not SPARKQL. That might help you when googling...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're making a classic mistake: confusing RDF (which is what SPARQL queries) with (one of) its serialisation, namely RDF/XML. `rdf:about` (and `rdf:ID`, `rdf:Description`, `rdf:resource`) are part of RDF/XML, a way RDF is written down. You can play around with the [RDF Validator](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/) to see what RDF triples result from a piece of RDF/XML.

In your case let's start with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF 
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.org/">
    <dc:title>Example for Donal Fellows</dc:title> 
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Plug that into [the validator](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/) and you get:

```
Number      Subject                      Predicate                        Object
1           http://www.example.org/      http://purl.org/dc/terms/title   "Example for Donal Fellows"
```

(you can also ask for a pictorial representation)

Notice that `rdf:about` is not present: its value provides the subject for the triple.

How do I do a query to find properties associated with `http://www.example.org`? Like this:

```
select * {
    <http://www.example.org/> ?predicate ?object
}
```

You'll get:

```
?predicate                        ?object
<http://purl.org/dc/terms/title>  "Example for Donal Fellows"
```

You'll notice that the query is a triple match with variables (`?v`) in places where we want to find values. We could also ask what predicate links `http://www.example.org/` with `"Example for..."` by asking:

```
select * {
    <http://www.example.org/> ?predicate "Example for Donal Fellows"
}
```

This pattern matching is the heart of SPARQL.

RDF/XML is a tricky beast, and you might find it easier to work with [N-Triples](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-think17/index.html), which is very verbose but clear, or [turtle](http://www.w3.org/2007/02/turtle/primer/), which is like N-Triples with a large number of shorthands and abbreviations. Turtle is often preferred by the rdf community.

P.S. `rdfs:about` doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: All true but you could also try semantic web questions at http://www.semanticoverflow.com/ where more expert folks hang out.